# Data-target no activa modals

Tags: python, bootstrap, flask

Buenas tardes a todos:

Estoy realizando un curso en Udemy para aprender Python, he finalizado un proyecto y del que creo que estoy seguro que la funcionalidad por parte del back-end(controlador) está funcionando perfectamente y me esta fallando la parte del front-end, en este caso o Jinja o Bootstrap y creo que es este ultimo el que me está dando el fallo.

A la hora de accionar el boton de eliminar o editar, no se me activan los formularios, la consola no me da ningun error y el JS creo que esta bien, puede que me venga del target de los botones, que no se estén conectando con los identificadores correspondientes.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="{{h._id}}" data-name="{{h.name}}" class="float-right btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveModal" data-id="{{h._id}}" data-name="{{h.name}}" class="float-right btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mr-2"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

Como veis tengo unos identificadores data-target en cada boton, que estoy conectando con dos vistas,
las cuales os debajo debajo.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#saveModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    Crear
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="saveModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" aria-modal="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form id="saveForm" action="{{url_for('hotel.add')}}" add_action="{{url_for('hotel.add')}}" update_action="{{url_for('hotel.update', id = 0)}}" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          {% include "hotel/form.html" %}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Crear</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    saveHotel();
  }

  const saveHotel = () => {

    const saveModal = document.querySelector('#saveModal')
    const saveForm = document.querySelector('#saveForm')

    if(document.querySelector("#saveModal .text-danger") != null) {
      const saveModalController = new bootstrap.Modal(saveModal)
      saveModalController.show()
    }

    saveModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', (e) => {

    const button = e.relatedTarget
    
    const id = button.getAttribute('data-id')
    const name = button.getAttribute('data-name')

    clearForm();

    if (id == null) {
      saveForm.setAttribute('action', saveForm.getAttribute('add_action'))
      document.querySelector('#saveModal .modal-title').textContent = 'Crear hotel'
    }else {
      saveForm.setAttribute('action', saveForm.getAttribute('update_action').slice( 0, -1) + id)
      document.querySelector('#saveModal .modal-title').textContent = `Actualizar hotel: ${name}`

      getInfoHotel(id)
    };
  });
  };

  const clearForm = () => {
    document.querySelector('#saveForm [name=name]').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#saveForm [name=place]').value = ''
  };

  const getInfoHotel = (id) => {
    console.log(id)
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/hotel/get-detial-by-id/' + id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      console.log(res)
      .then(res => {
        document.querySelector('#saveForm [name=name]').value = res.name
        document.querySelector('#saveForm [name=place]').value = res.place
      });
  };
</script>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" aria-modal="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form id="deleteForm" action="{{url_for('hotel.delete', id = 0)}}" delete_action="{{url_for('hotel.delete', id = 0)}}" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          ¿Desea eliminar el hotel?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Eliminar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const deleteHotel = () => {

    const deleteModal = document.querySelector('#deleteModal')
    const deleteForm = document.querySelector('#deleteForm')

    deleteModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', (e) => {

    let button = e.relatedTarget
    
    const id = button.getAttribute('data-id')
    const name = button.getAttribute('data-name')

    deleteForm.setAttribute('action', deleteForm.getAttribute('delete_action').slice( 0, -1) + id)
    document.querySelector('#deleteModal .modal-title').textContent = `Eliminar hotel: ${name}`;
  });

  };

  deleteHotel();
</script>
```

Os dejo tambien el index.html para que veais que estoy llamando correctamente a Bootstrap tanto css como JS.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% from 'partials/macro/pagination.html' import b_pagination %}

{% block content %}

    {% include "hotel/add_modal.html" %}
    {% include "hotel/delete_modal.html" %}

    <main class="row">

        {% for h in hotel.items %}
            <section class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 col-12 mt-2">
                <article class="card">
                    <article class="card-header">
                        <h4>{{ h.name }}</h4>
                        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="{{h._id}}" data-name="{{h.name}}" class="float-right btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveModal" data-id="{{h._id}}" data-name="{{h.name}}" class="float-right btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mr-2"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card-body">
                        {{ h.place }}
                    </article>
                </article>
            </section>
        {% endfor %}
    </main>

{{ b_pagination(hotel) }}

{% endblock %}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fontawesome/css/all.min.css')}}">
        <title>Flask Mongo</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}

        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cualquier dato mas que necesiteis, os contesto en la mayor brevedad, gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: Al trabajar con la versión 5 de Bootstrap, debes renombrar los valores de `data-*` por `data-bs-*`. Revisa tus botones para llamar los modales. Estás usando el método de la versión anterior.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Como bien dices, me faltaba añadir data-bs muchisimas gracias